# Are there any issues with changing the case on a GitHub repository or organization name?

Tags: git, github

If I have an organization and repository at `github.com/Name/Repo` and I'd like to rename it to `github.com/name/repo`, are there any issues that this could cause?

[GitHub's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/) says that the URLs are case-sensitive, but I have no problem cloning a URL with the incorrect case, or changing an existing repository's remote URL and then pushing and fetching. So existing clones wouldn't be affected.

Does anyone have more info on this? Is it safe?